# Modify feature: moving or change the shape

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, c#, editing

When the user makes some edit on features on ArcMap, the user can make some changes like moving the feature, editing the attributes or changing the shape.

How could I know if the user moved the feature or changed the shape?

I want to put different conditions on the editing according to what the user did.

Answer (score 1):

Recalculate the centroid of the shape; compare it to the old one. This should almost always change due to a move or reshape.